# customize shortcuts: remove 'hash pointer' and have only 'go to line' on CTRL+L

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, aptana, radrails

Hi all
In aptana Studio 3 I don't find useful `CTRL+L -> 1` for *'hash pointer'* and `CTRL+L -> 2` for *'go to line'* and I would like to get rid of the first one and easily go to line with `CTRL+L` and that's it. Anybody knows how to do it? - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the Hash Pointer ruby bundle command has a conflicting keybinding. You can go to Commands > Ruby > Edit this Bundle to grab down a copy of the bundle to your documents folder, then edit the ruby.ruble/commands/hash_pointer.rb file to change the keybinding.

But the issue you raise is important, on non-Mac systems Ctrl+L is the shortcut for go to line which is something we shouldn't conflict with. I can easily change it to something else for Win/Linux for everyone at the source. Here's a Lighthouse ticket to track that fix: https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/2402-ruby-command-hash-pointer-keybinding-conflicts-with-go-to-line-on-non-mac-oses